# Better memory management in bison

Tags: c++, bison

Bison by default uses union to store semantic types values. Since union doesn't support fields other than pointers, primitives, arrays and plain old data I ended up with raw pointers to shared_ptrs, that I have to free manually...

While it works, it is ugly and error prone and I would like to replace it with something better. [Here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.parsers.bison.general/2783) it is suggested that I can use `YYSTYPE` macro to supply my own semantic type, that would replace union. However suggested replacement seems too verbose for me.

Is there some example or reference page or any other suggestion that would help me write more safe bison parser? I'm not considering switching to other parser generator.

Comment: Actually in C++11 the requirements for classes to be stored in `union`s have been relaxed quite a bit.

Comment: Is it relaxed enough to have fields of type `shared_ptr`? I was sure that anything with custom constructor would cause compiler error.

Comment: I'm sure custom constructors are now allowed, but IIRC there are some restrictions anyway, I'll have to check the standard.

Comment: C++11 allows complex types like `sdhared_ptr` in unions, but you need to manually construct/destruct them at the right time (with placement new and explicit destructor calls), which is very error prone.

Comment: Exactly; see C++11 §9.5 (class.union) ¶2-4.

Comment: Thanks for information! Still that only confirms that I should discard union for something more suited for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One technique I've used is `#define YYSTYPE std::shared_ptr<Object>`, where `Object` is an abstract base class with a virtual destructor and plenty of virtual functions to all do the things needed by all the various subclasses of object.  This has a somewhat nasty "code smell" as you're effectively downcasting Object pointers to derived class pointers all over the place.

Just using raw pointers and making sure you clean up properly is not that hard -- every action needs to make sure it cleans up all the pointers allocated by the rules it uses directly (either by explicitly calling delete or by copying them into `$$` so it owns them), but as the actions are generally small (they mostly just call other functions), that is not too hard.  Then you just use `%destructor` declarations to ensure proper cleanup for things dropped after errors.

Comment: Actually that other approach is what I have in my code right now. It's memory leak free as far as I can tell (`valgrind`), yet I feel uneasy about all those `delete`s. I try out that abstract class approach - if only I had some pretty solution for casting objects back to what they where originally it would be perfect!